# Saving microtome value as variable to use twice

Tags: php

I am creating profile form where I am allowing users to store their profile photos. To make sure the names are different and won't be overwritten, I am using microtome function to rename the uploaded file:

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.'. end($temp);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],"subsites/uploads/". $newfilename
```

...but later when I call `$newfilename` variable in the same form (to save file path in the database) it values is changed.

```
<input type="hidden" name="FormPicName" id="FormFileName" 
value=<?php echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],"subsites/uploads/". $newfilename?>>
```

I tried storing $newfilename as variable or session variable, but it still generates different values.

**Is there a way to save microtome based variable as constant?**

Comment: why not checking if the file name already exists append -(integer) to the name and save it, because microtime is only avaliable for the systems that supports gettimeofday() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great solution (I use this for my projects)

```
// get file extension
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// make new filename
$newfilename = uniqid('profilepic_').'.'.$ext;
```

$newfilename will have something like profilepic_4b3403665fea6.jpg

Comment: Thanks! This is a good hint!
Although this solution still produces different variables. Different for the file name and different for the form field, which I use to store the path of the image on the server.
How do you save location of the file in your database?

Comment: ¡WOW! When you need link image to a DB record, just use insert_id. For example:
1- Put record in database
2- $newfilename = $result->insert_id.'.'.$ext;